# MySQL grouping attributes together

Tags: mysql, hash

I have a table which have repetitive values like id->attribute relation :

```
id   attribute
1    abc
2    blah
1    food
1    code
2    sleep
```

How can i index them, so that the attributes of a particular id gets together in the result?

```
id
1    abc   food   code
2    blah  sleep
```

Now hash for 1 will be same for all 1's in id. That's why I'm thinking Hashing?
If I'm right, please guide me how to apply it here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a query that will return all the values for an id on one line, the easiest way is using `group_concat()`:

```
select id, group_concat(attribute)
from table t
group by id;
```

If you want them in separate columns, then the problem is a bit harder.

I'm not sure what indexing or hash indexing has to do with this problem.  Those are basically internal methods used by a database in the engine, not part of the SQL language.

Comment: Thanks to clear my doubt about indexing. And one more thing, i wanted quick results from my query. So, does this query has to go through each tuple in the table to get the results?

Comment: @Cruze . . . If you care about performance you should modify your question (or ask another one) including information about the size of the tables and their structure.